# open and set up multiple blender files using python

Tags: scripting

I'm not a programmer, but I often use python to replace repetitive task on Blender. So one day, I made a mistake from the beginning. I end up fixing multiple files one by one. I need find to a way so I can automatically,

1. open blender file from list,
2. change the setting and
3. save it,
4. then open the next blender file again until the shots list is over.

every time I open a file using script, the script is gone then stop the process. I tried to google to find proper way to do it, and found this https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html. but I don't really know how to use it. can anyone help me give a sample or a resource material to make that kind of script. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, are there a lot of objects in each file ?

Comment: I use the script to do repetitive task. for example, I make the compositing layer into 3 part. I want to make the layer into 1 only. I have the script to change the layer from 3 to 1, but the problem is, I have to open the file one by one.

Comment: Maybe this will help ? Someone else has been struggling with that recently : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192060/86891

Comment: Thanks, let me check.